# $S: U \rightarrow V$, $T: V \rightarrow W$, $ \text{im } S = \text{ker } T.$ Then $SS^* + T^*T$ is an isomorphism from $V$ to $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Problem**
>
> Let $U$, $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional inner product spaces over
>   $F$.
>
> Let $S: U \rightarrow V$ and $T: V \rightarrow W$ be linear
>   transformations such that
>
> $$ \text{im } S = \text{ker } T.$$
>
> Prove that $SS^* + T^*T$ is an isomorphism from $V$ to $V$.

Claim: $S^*S(x) = 0$ if and only if $S(x)=0$ and $TT^*(x)=0$ if and only if $T^*(x)=0$.

If $S^*S(x) = 0$, then $ 0 = \langle {x,S^*S(x)} \rangle = \langle {S(x),S(x)} \rangle $, so $S(x)=0$.

If $S(x) = 0$, then $S^*S(x) = S^*(0) = 0$.

Similarly, $TT^*(x)=0$ if and only if $T^*(x)=0$.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: If you tell us what you've tried, we can better help you understand how to solve problems like this. You can tell us by clicking on "edit" beneath your question to add detail. Also: perhaps you could look at the case where $U = \Bbb R^1, V = W =\Bbb R^2, S(x) = (x, x), T(x, y) = (x - y, 0)$ and try to figure out something useful by writing out the details of that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: prove that $TT^*w=0$ if and only if $T^*w=0$; similarly, $S^*Su=0$ if and only if $Su=0$.

Suppose $(SS^*+T^*T)x=0$; then
$$
T^*Tx=-SS^*x\in\operatorname{im}S
$$
which implies $TT^*Tx=0$.

Therefore $T^*Tx=0$ by the hint. Can you finish?

Comment: Then $T(x)=0$ implies $x=0$, so the map $SS^* + T^*T$ is 1-1 and thus an isomorphism. Am i right?

Comment: @StarChou Yes: $T^*Tx=0$ implies $SS^*x=0$, and then, if $u=S^*x$, $S^*Su=0$, so $u=0$. Hence the map has trivial kernel. Finite dimensionality allows to finish.